# How can I compute (for later uses) a wave wtih a very high frequency?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, math, physics

I'm running a physics simulation related to visible light, and the resulting wave function has a very, very high frequency -- cyclic frequency is on the order of `1.0e15`, and the spatial frequency `k` is on the order of `1.0e7`. Thankfully, I only use the spatial frequency, but when I calculate it for later usage (using either `math` or `numpy`), I get something that resembles a beat wave, unless I use `N` ~= `k` sample points, because I have to calculate it over a much greater range (on the order of `1.0e-3 - 1.0e-1`). It produces a beat wave so consistently I spent a few hours to make sure I'm not actually calculating one. I'll also have to use `fft()` on the resulting wave and I'm afraid it won't work properly with a misrepresented wave.

I've tried using various amounts of sample points, but unless it's extraordinarily high (takes a good minute or two to calculate), only the prominence of beating changes. Just in case I'm misusing numpy, I tried the same thing with appending `wave.value` calculated by `math.sin` to a float array, but it had the same result.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mmScale = 1.0e-3
nmScale = 1.0e-9
c = 3.0e8
N = 1000

class Wave:
    def __init__(self, amplitude, wavelength):
        self.wavelength = wavelength*nmScale
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        self.omega = 2*pi*c/self.wavelength
        self.k = 2*pi/self.wavelength
    def value(self, time, travel):
        return self.amplitude*np.sin(self.omega*time - self.k*travel)

x = np.linspace(50, 250, N)*mmScale
wave = Wave(1, 400)
y = wave.value(0.1, x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The code above produces a graph of the function, and you can put in different values for `N` to see how it gives different waveforms.

Comment: It's normal aliasing effect when sampling frequency does not satisfy Nyquist criterion. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: Given you know the spacial frequency, why don't you use distances which are `2*n*pi` or smth apart, so that the `self.k*travel` always contributes the same amount and you only get the time development? I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sampling spatial frequency is:

```
1/Ts = 1 / ((250-50)*mmScale) / N) = 5000 [samples/meter]
```

Your wave's spatial frequency is:

```
1/Tw = 1 / wavelength = 1 / (400e-9) = 2500000 [wavelengths/meter]
```

You fail to satisfy Nyquist criterion by a factor of `(2*2500000 ) / 5000 = 1000`.
Thus you must expect serious aliasing effects. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing.

Not much can be done to battle it. But there are some tricks that may help you depending on application. One is to represent a wave as a complex envelop around carier frequency, which is 400e-9. Please provide more detail on what you do with the wave.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. As for the details, I've been given a summer practice task to create a Michelson interferometer simulation for visible, monochrome (might change later on). I've been told that the resulting interference will be a sine wave of some sort that depends on the distance between the splitter and the movable mirror), and the task is to find it and then use `fft()` on it, although I can't really tell what the point of the FFT is, in this case.